# SharePoint list: creates ';#' in choice columns after saving new item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, dropdown, choice-field

I have a SharePoint list to which I add rows by filling 'New Item' form. One of the columns in my list is a choice column with multiple options and which also allows to add values manually. When I choose one of the options from a drop-down menu in the 'New Item' form and save it, SharePoint adds a new option to drop down menu with ';#' in front and in the end. See attached[image].

Any tips on how to avoid this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following steps to troubleshooting this issue.

1.Delete this choice column and create a new choice column again.

2.Did you change the choice column default column formatting? Here is my default column formatting:

```
{"elmType":"div","style":{"flex-wrap":"wrap","display":"flex"},"children":[{"elmType":"div","style":{"box-sizing":"border-box","padding":"4px 8px 5px 8px","display":"flex","border-radius":"16px","height":"24px","align-items":"center","white-space":"nowrap","overflow":"hidden","margin":"4px 4px 4px 4px"},"attributes":{"class":{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 1"]},"sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCornflowerBlue",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 2"]},"sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 3"]},"sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGold",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField",""]},"","sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary"]}]}]}]}},"children":[{"elmType":"span","style":{"line-height":"16px","height":"14px"},"attributes":{"iconName":{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 1"]},"",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 2"]},"",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 3"]},"",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField",""]},"",""]}]}]}]},"class":{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 1"]},"",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 2"]},"",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 3"]},"",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField",""]},"",""]}]}]}]}}},{"elmType":"span","style":{"overflow":"hidden","text-overflow":"ellipsis","padding":"0 3px"},"txtContent":"@currentField","attributes":{"class":{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 1"]},"sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-CornflowerBlueFont",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 2"]},"sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-MintGreenFont",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField","Choice 3"]},"sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-GoldFont",{"operator":":","operands":[{"operator":"==","operands":["@currentField",""]},"",""]}]}]}]}}}]}],"templateId":"BgColorChoicePill"}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried step 1 and it did not help. Regarding 2. - how/where can I check the column formatting? Was not able to find it.

Comment: You could find column formatting in list settings. In list setting click your choice column then you could edit column formatting in "Edit Column" page.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? Comment here if you still need any help.